# Need help in inserting data to my Access database

Tags: database, vb.net, insert

I'm just a beginner in having database. Its my first time using database in VB, but my error won't let me insert my data into my table. I'm hoping if anyone can correct my errors?

Thanks in advance!

```
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = Z:\VIAJE_Exercises\MachineExercise7\databaseEnrolled.accdb;Persist Security Info=True")

    Dim insertsql As String

    Try
        insertsql = "INSERT INTO databaseEnrolled" & _
        "(ID, year, studentID, firstName, middleInitial, lastName, age, gender, birthday, citizenship, religion, placeOfBirth, address, guardian, contact) " & _
        " VALUES(@ID, @year, @studentID, @firstName, @middleInitial, @lastName, @age, @gender, @birthday, @citizenship, @religion, @placeOfBirth, @address, @guardian, @contact)"

        Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(insertsql, conn)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", year.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", studentIdtxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstNametxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middleInitial", middleTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastNametxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", ageTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", genderCom.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthday", monthCom.Text + dayCom.Text + yearCom.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@citizenship", citizenshipTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@religion", religionTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@placeOfBirth", placeOfBirthTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", addressTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guardian", guardianTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", contactTxt.Text)

        conn.Open()
        Dim rowsaffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        MessageBox.Show(rowsaffected.ToString & "added")
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: What error is it? Can you post it?

Comment: What is the connection string?

Comment: I mean, if there is an error,  the messagebox should prompt the error message for the exception. What is indicated in the messagebox?

Comment: the error is it cant find Z:\VIAJE_Exercises\MachineExercise7\databaseEnrolled.accdb

Comment: Then check to see if the database really does exists in that location. Is it there?

Answer (score 1):

The first problem, as you supplied above, is because your database is not found in the directory indicated in your connection string. You should correct the issue before proceeding.

I also see that you are using MS Access 2007 or newer version. The format of your Conn is wrong as it is intended only before Access 2007.

Change your connectionstring into:

```
   Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Z:\VIAJE_Exercises\MachineExercise7\databaseEnrolled.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;
```

Salamat,

**Update:**

Oh, it is too late for me to notice that you are using an MS Access reserved word. "Year," for example, is one of those. You have to enclose it in [] such as [Year] in the following code:

```
insertsql = "INSERT INTO databaseEnrolled" & _
        "(ID, [year], studentID, firstName, middleInitial, lastName, age, gender, birthday, citizenship, religion, placeOfBirth, address, guardian, contact) " & _
        " VALUES(@ID, @year, @studentID, @firstName, @middleInitial, @lastName, @age, @gender, @birthday, @citizenship, @religion, @placeOfBirth, @address, @guardian, @contact)"
```

Aside from "year," is there any other reserved word in your query? I am not so sure, but you can try to do that again to the other fields if in doubt to prevent your errors.

Mabuhay ang Pinas.

Comment: now ive giot new error, syntax error in insert into statements

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your input query is trying to insert the value for @year into the ID field of your database. Two things you can do to try to remedy this are.

1. If your ID field is an auto-increment primary key field you can remove it completely from the insert query and it will automatically fill with the next available number.
2. Make sure your parameters are in order. So if ID is the first in your input query, you need to make id the first parameter below.